# How to do mapping as arraylist of maps for below using dataweave mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, mule-esb

How to do mapping for below data.

```
ParameterMap{[card=[15242424211], phone=[54545454545]]}
```

This data is dynamic which is coming from http request as part queryparameters. I want to form query params in the form #[{'p1':'v1', 'p2':'v2'}] dynamically

for example into `[{'card': '15242424211','phone':'54545454545'}]`

i.e Array of maps(application/java) Using Dataweave in mule
can you please help on this

Answer (score 1):

use following code

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
inboundProperties."http.query.params" mapObject {
    ($$) : $[0]
}
```

With this output will be  `{"card": "15242424211","phone":"54545454545"}` you can wrap it under array if required by using

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
[inboundProperties."http.query.params" mapObject {
    ($$) : $[0]
}]
```

This will produce output as `[{"card": "15242424211","phone":"54545454545"}]`
Please refer `org.mule.module.http.internal.ParameterMap` for details of HTTP params.

Hope this help.

Update:-
Please use following for setting query parameters for HTTP outbound request.

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
inboundProperties."http.query.params" mapObject {
    ($$) : $[0]
}
]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
```

Comment: Getting below error when i am hitting outbound HTTP with query param ...<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Length Required</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Length Required</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.</p>
</BODY></HTML>.. can you please help on this

Comment: as per below link format(should be map). For testing i have hardcoded data and tested. Even after it is not working https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/http-request-connector#adding-custom-parameters

Comment: Please check undated answer. I have tested it and working fine for me.

Comment: Mapping is working well but http queryparams expression is not accepting format. can you please help

Comment: Please post code snippet of dataweave and http request.